# How to jQuery ajax multiple selects

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

OK, my form is :

```
<form>

<select name="students" id="students">
<option value="0">Select Value First</option>
<option value="a">Value A</option>
<option value="b">Value B</option>
<option value="c">Value C</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<select name="house" id="house">
<option value="0">Select Value Second</option>
<option value="a">Value A</option>
<option value="b">Value B</option>
<option value="c">Value C</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<select name="location" id="location">
<option value="0">Select Value Third</option>
<option value="a">Value A</option>
<option value="b">Value B</option>
<option value="c">Value C</option>
</select>
<br /><br />

</form>
```

My jQuery is:

```
$(document).on("change","select",function() {
$val1 = $(this).val();
$val2 = $(this).attr('name');
    $.get("selectdata.php",{"name":$val2,"id":$val1},function($data){
            $("#result").html($data);
        });
});
```

What I want to achieve is: when the page loads, all students should be displayed. So my query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'mytable' 
WHERE 'students' = 'students.val()' AND 'house'='house.val()' 
  AND 'location'='location.val()';
```

When any option from select is selected, only that value should be changed in the `SELECT` statement. So for example, if anything from SELECT HOUSE is changed, the new `SELECT` statement will be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'mytable' 
WHERE 'students' = 'students.val()' 
  AND 'house' = 'changedVALUE' 
  AND 'location' = 'location.val()';`
```

After this is anything from the `SELECT` LOCATION is changed, only the location value should be passed to the existing `SELECT` with condition for house selected in previous operation.

So basically I want the previous condition to be intact and pass the new condition on `SELECT` change.

I hope I am able to explain my issue. I am not sure how to create the jQuery / PHP query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jquery should be like this:

```
  $("#students, #house, #location").on("change", function(){
  var students = $("#students").val();
  var house = $("#house").val();  
  var location = $("#location").val();
  $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: 'selectdata.php',
    data : { 'students': students, 'house':house, 'location':location },
    success: function(data){
      $("#result").html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Then your `selectdata.php` should be like this

```
<?php 
   $students = $_POST['students'];
   $house = $_POST['house'];
   $location = $_POST['location'];

   //sql query
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'mytable' WHERE 'students'= $students AND 'house'= $house AND 'location'= $location;"
?>
```

**Edit**

jquery:

```
function getData(){
  var students = $("#students").val();
  var house = $("#house").val();  
  var location = $("#location").val();
  $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: 'selectdata.php',
    data : { 'students': students, 'house':house, 'location':location },
    success: function(data){
      $("#result").html(data);
    }
  });
  }

  $( document ).ready(function() {
    getData();
  });      


  $("#students, #house, #location").on("change", function(){
      getData();
  });
```

And in `selectdata.php`

```
<?php 
   $students = $_POST['students'];
   $house = $_POST['house'];
   $location = $_POST['location'];

   $conditions = array(); //initialize array for conditions in the where clause
   if($students != 0){ //if value is not equal to 0, add to array.
       $conditions[] = "students = " . $students;
   }
   if($house != 0){ //if value is not equal to 0, add to array.
       $conditions[] = "house = " . $house;
   }
   if($location!= 0){ //if value is not equal to 0, add to array.
       $conditions[] = "location = " . $location;
   }

   $where = "";
   if(count($conditions) > 0){ //if array is not empty
      $where = "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $conditions); // sample output: "WHERE students = 1 AND house = 2 AND location = 3"
   }

   //now your sql
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'mytable' " . $where; // "SELECT * FROM 'mytable' WHERE students = 1 AND house = 2 AND location = 3"
   // if the $condition array is empty, the sql should look like this: "SELECT * from 'mytable'"
```

Comment: Thank you master. Exactly what i wanted. Just one stupid query. How do i nest it in a if statement so that if nothing is selected, the selectdata.php should still show in the result div. Thanks a ton.

Comment: What do you mean nothing is selected?

Comment: I mean the default selection is `Select Value First`, `Select Value Secondt`, `Select Value Third` with value=0 for all of them. So in my selectdata.php i will be showing all the results, i want that to appear by default in the result div. And when the select changes, your solution works perfect!

Comment: i think i got it .. 
i did this: 
`$.ajax({
  url: "77selectdata.php",
}).done(function(data) { 
  $('#resultdiv').html(data);
}); 
`
 And in the selectdata.php, i added a `if (!empty($_POST)){` condition. And it shows the expected result before changing anything. Thanks again!

Comment: What if I changed back to `Select Value First` all the select inputs?

Comment: Yeah still scratching my head on this. The value passed is 0 and not able to query the database with a `WHERE something = 0`. How do i resolve this?

Comment: Thanks a million. I got it working. I defined the array in the check itself.

`$conditions = array();
 if(!empty($_POST['student'])){ $student = $_POST['student']; $conditions[] = "'student' = '" . $student."'"; echo $student."<br /><br /><br />";}
 if(!empty($_POST['house'])){ $house = $_POST['house']; $conditions[] = "'house' = " . $house; echo $house."<br /><br /><br />";}
 if(!empty($_POST['religion'])){ $religion = $_POST['religion']; $conditions[] = "'religion' = " . $religion; echo $religion."<br /><br /><br />";}`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM 'mytable' WHERE 'students'='students.val()' AND 'house'='changedVALUE' AND 'location'='location.val()';

**UPDATED**

In the above query you used table & column  name inside `''` .
The correct syntax is :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE students='students.val()' && house='changedVALUE' && location='location.val()';
```

AND in **Javascript**, for making a variable ,use `var` instead of using `$` because it's used in PHP.Your code contains many mistakes.

Comment: thanks. but this is just a pseudo code. I want help with the jquery construct.